# Como pegar o value de uma tag e mandar para outra tag com js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Olá, pessoal estou com um problema que é o seguinte.

Tenho 4 tags iguais, mas eu quero mandar o valor da tag que foi clicada para o value do input.

Exemplo :

```
<img id="imgs" src="img_01">
<img id="imgs" src="img_02">
<img id="imgs" src="img_03">
<img id="imgs" src="img_04">
<input type="text" nome="selecionar_img" value="">
```

Suponhamos que eu clico na img de src 3, preciso que o meu input dessa forma.

```
<input type="text" nome="selecionar_img" value="img_03">
```

E se eu clicar em outra tag img o campo value apague o valor anterior e coloque o novo valor da tag que foi clicada.

```
    <input type="text" nome="selecionar_img" value="img_03"> // Valor anterior
    <input type="text" nome="selecionar_img" value="img_01"> // Novo Valor passado
```

Agradeço a quem poder me ajudar, não tenho experiência com Js mas preciso fazer esses eventos. obg ^-^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de tudo, duas observações: todas as suas tags `img` possuem o mesmo valor no atributo `id`. Segundo a especificação *html*, o valor desse elemento [deve ser único](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute). Esses valores deveriam estar no atributo `class`. Além disso, o nome do atributo no `input` é `name` e não `nome`.

Sendo assim, suas tags ficariam dessa forma:

```
<img class="imgs" src="img_01">
<img class="imgs" src="img_02">
<img class="imgs" src="img_03">
<img class="imgs" src="img_04">
<input type="text" name="selecionar_img" value="">
```

Para preencher o `input` com o atributo `src` da imagem, você pode fazer desse modo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".imgs").click(function(){
        $("input[name=selecionar_img]").val($(this).attr('src'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, pelo html eu apenas digitei aqui, não peguei do code que estou fazendo foi apenas pra fazer um exemplo raso msm, mas o js funcionou perfeitamente da maneira que eu estava querendo. obg pela ajuda

Comment: @Delacroix Sem problema. Como algum novato pode ter alguma dúvida semelhante e cair nessa página, evidenciei esses erros para evitar que alguém os reproduza.